# Reason of "java.lang.LinkageError: previously initiated loading for a different type with name"

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I've read a post https://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html and I use the demo code to simulate LinkageError.

```
/**
 * A self-first delegating classloader. It only loads specified classes self-first; other
 * classes are loaded from the parent.
 */
private static class CustomCL extends ClassLoader {

    private Set<String> selfFirstClasses;
    private String label;

    public CustomCL(String name, ClassLoader parent, String... selfFirsNames) {
        super(parent);
        this.label = name;
        this.selfFirstClasses = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(selfFirsNames));
    }

    public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (selfFirstClasses.contains(name)) {
            try {
                byte[] buf = new byte[100000];
                String loc = name.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
                InputStream inp = Demo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(loc);
                int n = inp.read(buf);
                inp.close();
                System.out.println(label + ": Loading " + name + " in custom classloader");
                return defineClass(name, buf, 0, n);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException(name, e);
            }
        }

        // Is never executed in this test
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
    }

    public Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (findLoadedClass(name) != null) {
            System.out.println(label + ": already loaded(" + name + ")");
            return findLoadedClass(name);
        }

        // Override parent-first behavior into self-first only for specified classes
        if (selfFirstClasses.contains(name)) {
            return findClass(name);
        } else {
            System.out.println(label + ": super.loadclass(" + name + ")");
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}

public static class User {

}

public static class LoginEJB {

    static {
        System.out.println("LoginEJB loaded");
    }

    public static void login(User u) {
    }
}

public static class Servlet {

    public static void doGet() {
        User u = new User();
        System.out.println("Logging in with User loaded in " + u.getClass().getClassLoader());
        LoginEJB.login(u);
    }
}

private static class EjbCL extends CustomCL {

    public EjbCL(ClassLoader parent, String... selfFirsNames) {
        super("Ejb", parent, selfFirsNames);
    }
}

private static class SfWebCL extends CustomCL {

    public SfWebCL(ClassLoader parent, String... selfFirsNames) {
        super("SFWeb", parent, selfFirsNames);
    }
}

public static void test1() throws Exception {
    CustomCL ejbCL = new EjbCL(Demo.class.getClassLoader(), "com.test.zim.Demo$User",
            "com.test.zim.Demo$LoginEJB");
    CustomCL sfWebCL = new SfWebCL(ejbCL, "com.test.zim.Demo$User",
            "com.test.zim.Demo$Servlet");

    System.out.println("Logging in, self-first");
    sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$Servlet", false).getMethod("doGet").invoke(null);
//      sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$Servlet", false).getMethod("doGet");
//      sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$User", false);
//      sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$LoginEJB", false).getMethods();


    System.out.println("Examining methods of LoginEJB");
    ejbCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$LoginEJB", false).getMethods();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        test1();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

---

After I run the test code, the output is:

```
Logging in, self-first
SFWeb: Loading com.test.zim.Demo$Servlet in custom classloader
SFWeb: super.loadclass(java.lang.Object)
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.lang.Object)
SFWeb: Loading com.test.zim.Demo$User in custom classloader
SFWeb: super.loadclass(java.lang.System)
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.lang.System)
SFWeb: super.loadclass(java.lang.StringBuilder)
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.lang.StringBuilder)
SFWeb: super.loadclass(java.lang.Class)
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.lang.Class)
SFWeb: super.loadclass(java.io.PrintStream)
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.io.PrintStream)
Logging in with User loaded in SFWeb
SFWeb: super.loadclass(com.test.zim.Demo$LoginEJB)
Ejb: Loading com.test.zim.Demo$LoginEJB in custom classloader
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.lang.Object)
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.lang.System)
Ejb: super.loadclass(java.io.PrintStream)
LoginEJB loaded
Examining methods of LoginEJB
Ejb: already loaded(com.test.zim.Demo$LoginEJB)
Ejb: Loading com.test.zim.Demo$User in custom classloader
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/test/zim/Demo$EjbCL) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "com/test/zim/Demo$User"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.test.zim.Demo$CustomCL.findClass(Demo.java:39)
    at com.test.zim.Demo$CustomCL.loadClass(Demo.java:57)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at com.test.zim.Demo.test1(Demo.java:117)
    at com.test.zim.Demo.main(Demo.java:146)
```

---

I really didn't get why it show the linkage error, and when I change the code

```
    sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$Servlet", false).getMethod("doGet").invoke(null);
```

to

```
    sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$Servlet", false).getMethod("doGet");
    sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$User", false);
    sfWebCL.loadClass("com.test.zim.Demo$LoginEJB", false).getMethods();
```

The error disappeared, I've got some questions:

1. Before I change the code, how is the linkageError happened? I think the class "com/test/zim/Demo$User" should coexist in two different classloader without any problem, since the two classloader invoke their own defineClass method? And why the error said ejbClassLoader load the User class with a different name, I think it's the first time EJBClassLoader load the User class?
2. After I change the code, I write some code to load the "User" and "LoginEJB" class manually, instead of invoke the "doGet()" method, what's the difference between the two code snippet, why there is no error in the latter code?
3. The error was occur in the ClassLoader.defineClass() phase, what does defineClass() really mean?
4. The ClassLoader.findLoadedClass() method, is it mean find the class (eg Foo.class) the ClassLoader ever load? If its parent ClassLoader have loaded the Foo.class before, it should return true. But if the child classloader load the Foo.class firstly, the parent classloader should load it again, and there would be two Foo.class, and they will coexist without problem?

Comment: http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html